# How to keep a footer down

Tags: html, css

I cannot keep the footer at the bottom of the page for both desktop and mobile. can someone please go over my code and tell me how to fix it?

The issue is it keeps going back to the center of the page and i am unable to move it down and have it stay there for most browsers and devices.

I have looked around for fixes and there are a few but the ones iv tried just ruin the entire page and push it all out of alignment. I am looking for the smallest amount of code possible to do this i don't want a giant chunk of code for this. i wanna keep it simple. I am new to web development. This is my first website.

This is the index.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>THG Graphics</title>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  body,
  h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif
  }
  
  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 6px
  }
  
  .w3-row-padding img {
    margin-bottom: 12px
  }
  
  .dropdownmobile {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .border {
    width: 24.%;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: inline-block
  }
  
  .dropbtn {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: thin;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .dropbtn:hover,
  .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #989898
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1500px">

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:32px 16px">
      <h1>THG Graphics</h1>
      <h1 class="w3-xlarge">Graphic Designer</h1>
      <div class="w3-padding-32">
        <div class="border">
          <a title="Home" href="index.html" class="w3-button w3-grey dropbtn">Home</a>
          <a title="Portfolio" href="portfolio.html" class="w3-button dropbtn">Portfolio</a>
          <a title="Enquiry" href="Enquiry.html" alt="Enquiry" class="w3-button dropbtn">Enquiry</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button title="About" alt="About" class="w3-button dropdown dropbtn dropdownmobile">About</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
              <a title="Contact us" href="Contact.html" alt="Contact us" class="w3-button">Contact us</a>
              <a title="Terms of use" href="TOS.html" alt="Terms of use" class="w3-button">Terms of use</a>
              <a href="#" title="Privacy policy" href="Privacypolicy.html" alt="Privacy Policy" class=" w3-button">Privacy Policy</a>
              <a title="FAQ" href="FAQ.html" alt="FAQ" class=" w3-button">FAQ</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Welcome to THG Graphics!</h2>
        <h5>We make custom Logos, Animated Logos &amp; Animations to suit your needs.</h5>
        <h5>Please check out our portfolio to view some of our work.</h5>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <footer class="w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey w3-center footer">
    <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2017 - All Rights Reserved - THG-Graphics.com</p>
    <div>
      <a href="TOS.html" class="w3-hover-text-blue">Terms of use</a>
      <a href="Privacypolicy.html" class="w3-hover-text-blue">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="FAQ.html" class="w3-hover-text-blue">FAQ</a>
    </div>
    <p>Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" target="_blank" class="w3-hover-text-green">w3.css</a></p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>THG Graphics</title>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  body,
  h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif
  }
  
  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 6px
  }
  
  .w3-row-padding img {
    margin-bottom: 12px
  }
  
  .dropdownmobile {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .border {
    width: 24.%;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: inline-block
  }
  
  .dropbtn {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: thin;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .dropbtn:hover,
  .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #989898
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1500px">

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="w3-panel w3-center w3-opacity" style="padding:32px 16px">
      <h1>THG Graphics</h1>
      <h1 class="w3-xlarge">Graphic Designer</h1>
      <div class="w3-padding-32">
        <div class="border">
          <a title="Home" href="index.html" class="w3-button w3-grey dropbtn">Home</a>
          <a title="Portfolio" href="portfolio.html" class="w3-button dropbtn">Portfolio</a>
          <a title="Enquiry" href="Enquiry.html" alt="Enquiry" class="w3-button dropbtn">Enquiry</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button title="About" alt="About" class="w3-button dropdown dropbtn dropdownmobile">About</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
              <a title="Contact us" href="Contact.html" alt="Contact us" class="w3-button">Contact us</a>
              <a title="Terms of use" href="TOS.html" alt="Terms of use" class="w3-button">Terms of use</a>
              <a href="#" title="Privacy policy" href="Privacypolicy.html" alt="Privacy Policy" class=" w3-button">Privacy Policy</a>
              <a title="FAQ" href="FAQ.html" alt="FAQ" class=" w3-button">FAQ</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Welcome to THG Graphics!</h2>
        <h5>We make custom Logos, Animated Logos &amp; Animations to suit your needs.</h5>
        <h5>Please check out our portfolio to view some of our work.</h5>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <footer class="w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey w3-center footer">
    <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2017 - All Rights Reserved - THG-Graphics.com</p>
    <div>
      <a href="TOS.html" class="w3-hover-text-blue">Terms of use</a>
      <a href="Privacypolicy.html" class="w3-hover-text-blue">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="FAQ.html" class="w3-hover-text-blue">FAQ</a>
    </div>
    <p>Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" target="_blank" class="w3-hover-text-green">w3.css</a></p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify a bit the problem, say your HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="header">HEADER</div>
   <div class="container">CONTENT</div>
   <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Now that's how the CSS code could look like:

```
html,
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.header {
   background: blue;
}

.container {
   background: red;
   padding-bottom: 100px; 
}

.footer {
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   background: yellow;
}
```

Note that you need to add a bottom padding of exactly the height of your footer (100px here) to your container to make it work.

The magic here happens because you set the min-height of your wrapper to be always equal to 100%, which forces your div to fit the view port height.

And your footer will be at the bottom of the page no matter what.

Hope this helps !

Comment: That doesn't work for me and is also very complicated because id need to basically remake the entire page. Im sure i could easily do this with like 2 lines of css how ever every time i fix it for desktop it breaks it on mobile. so if i fix it on mobile it breaks it on desktop. even moving the footer around past my javascript can break it. its odd.

Comment: Hmm ok I will try to check with your code as soon as I can then but I cannot access my computer just now. did you try playing with the min height of your container?:)

Comment: G'day Alex, i re built my entire website using what you linked above and it fixed my issue. i did get a lot of issues how ever all now works. My footer is now dynamic to the screen size. thank you for your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's great if it all works now !  For the other issues in your project, if you cannot get it work completely maybe you could write an other question :) Have a great day Sean!

Comment: Cheers you too Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.footer {position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: where am i ment to put this line? Replace my footer classes with that line?

Comment: Ah I see that you are using the w3 css stylesheet. Sorry I thought you wrote all your CSS by hand. So you can copy and paste this line of code after ".dropdown a:hover { background-color: #989898}" and before the "</style>" tag and the footer should stay at the bottom. Let me know if it doesn't work !

Comment: Btw the solution I gave you is a band-aid fix. You will probably encounter a problem of content hiding behind the footer if you shrink the screen down enough in the future. If you want to properly learn CSS, I suggest not using the w3 template since their code may have funky interactions with your own (like the footer not staying down) and writing your own custom code. If you have problems getting started, lemme know if I can help : )

Comment: i just used a ton of <br> attributes and it moved the footer down but its not dynamic to screen size so if the screen is too big its going to be half way up the screen. i don't feel like completely redesigning my website by making a style sheet. if i make a new style sheet i wont be able to keep the current look of the site, i like how it looks atm so using w3 is easy and works atm. I am currently working on a separate page for now fixing something else so later on ill deal with my home page footer. thanks anyway though :D

Comment: i tried using the line above i actually had written that up by hand b4 i made this thread and that didnt work for mobile but worked for desktop.